# Dúvida sobre como implementar uma Injeção de Dependência no C# utilizando o Ninject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

Tenho um projeto C# com Windows Forms. Estou com uma dúvida sobre como fazer uma implementação entre duas camadas da minha aplicação: *`Application` e `WindowsForms`*.

Preciso carregar um `DataGridView` com uma lista de `"PessoaTipo"`.

Eu criei uma instância da minha classe Application `PessoaTipoAppService` no `WindowsForms` e chamei a função `_PessoaTipoApp.GetAll()`, só que quando carrego pelo *construtor*, dá erro pela falta da implementação da Injeção de Dependência com o Ninject.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly IPessoaTipoAppService _PessoaTipoApp;

        public Form1(IPessoaTipoAppService PessoaTipoApp)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _PessoaTipoApp = PessoaTipoApp;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _PessoaTipoApp.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma força?
Deixei o projeto disponível para download. Aí podemos postar a solução aqui neste tópico...

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo Minimo:

Instale o pacote pelo ***[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/)*** ou `Package Manager Console`

> `Install-Package Ninject`

Crie um classe que é responsável em resolver as dependências:

> `FormModule`

```
using Ninject.Modules;
public class FormModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMount>().To<Mount>();
    }

    public static FormModule Create()
    {
        return new FormModule();
    }
}
```

no método `Load` chame o `Bind` para configuração das classes e coloque todas as classes que serão utilizadas no seu projeto e que são dependências de outros formulários.

---

Crie uma classe que será responsável em instanciar os `Form` e consequentemente as ***suas dependencias***:

> `FormResolve`

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;
public class FormResolve
{
    private static IKernel _ninjectKernel;

    public static void Wire(INinjectModule module)
    {
        _ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(module);
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _ninjectKernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

No arquivo `Program.cs` configure da seguinte forma:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            FormResolve.Wire(FormModule.Create());
            Application.Run(FormResolve.Resolve<Form1>());
        }    
    }
}
```

Com essas duas classes e a configuração feita no `Program.cs` já está pronto para resolver dependências.

***Exemplo:*** `Form1`

```
using Ninject;
using System.Windows.Forms;  
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private IMount Mount { get; set; }

        [Inject()]
        public Form1(IMount mount)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Mount = mount;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = Mount?.GetDateTime().ToLongDateString();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = FormResolve.Resolve<Form2>();
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Para chamar o `form2` ou qualquer `form` siga o exemplo do botão abaixo onde `form1` chama o `form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = FormResolve.Resolve<Form2>();
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Ninject](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/)
- [Dependency Injection in WinForms using Ninject and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127763/dependency-injection-in-winforms-using-ninject-and-entity-framework)
- [How to use Ninject in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129092/how-to-use-ninject-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio....A classe Program.cs está dando erro (Sublinhando de vermelho ainda....) ;

Comment: Depende a versão que você instalou o Ninject, o vermelho deve ser `obsoleto`, por favor confira isso e se for isso instale o NInject estavel que é a versão `Install-Package Ninject -Version 3.2.2`

Comment: Sim, foi instalada a versão mais recente do Ninject... O problema é que em Program.cs é como se o Application não estivesse mais disponível ou sem referência...

Comment: Olha só, eu vi o seu projeto, está faltando nela `class` acabei lembrando por isso eu fiz um exemplo minimo como deve ser, no seu projeto era impossível eu ficar codificando era por esse motivo que resolvi contribuir com uma resposta dessa forma, sendo um projeto ideal para adaptação com o seu. Ou seja, o erro é do seu projeto e não da minha proposta.

Comment: Ok Virgilio. De todas as formas, obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Olha @JalberRomano desculpa alguma coisa, mas, o seu projeto anexado na pergunta faltam `class` e isso meio que foge da regra da daqui a gente proponha solução, inclusive essa é funcional além disso é que o projeto em questão faltam `class`!